# How to pass variable in one .py cgi to other python cgi script

Tags: python, variables, cgi, text-files

I want to pass a variable in one python cgi script to other cgi script? how can i do this as in php. using url or something...?

i saved variable in text file, thus read and get saved variable when other page load

Is this method good?

Comment: with regard to your question about whether saving the variable in the text file is a good method: consider what might happen if *two* people used your Web page at one time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally this is done using cookies or hidden form fields.

Comment: haven't we some posh method as in php?

Comment: Yes, if you use a Web framework (e.g. Flask, Django, Pyramid) you will get a session object that abstracts that stuff for you.